# how to use InternetSetOption

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, function

How to use InternetSetOption? I go throught the details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It also says something related with OptionFlags. Anybody know how to use the second parameter to the function ?. The information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Its little bit confusing,  for example

`INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE`: 50:

> Sets or retrieves an unsigned long integer value that contains the connected state. This is used by InternetQueryOption and InternetSetOption.

What does it mean if I pass a 50 as the second parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Generally speaking, you shouldn't be trying to *set* the INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE, as this is set automatically by the system and allows you to collect information about the status of the system's network connection.

You generally use the InternetSetOption API thusly:

```
// Announce to the world that we've changed the proxy
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

// ISSUE: We're using ANSI here because calling functions marshal in ANSI. MSDN suggests that W-versions might not work in older IE versions.
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]  
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int Option, [In] IntPtr buffer, Int32 BufferLength);
```

But if you're doing something more complicated, like setting the proxy using INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION, you can use a different signature to more easily pass in the required structure.